# EC2: Allowing multiple IPs for a security group rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In EC2-classic, I've been trying to use a security group as the source for another security group, to allow access from multiple IPs (work and home).  The way I've been trying is to make a security group named 'my_ips' with one rule for each of my ip numbers (as CIDR), open for all TCP ports.  Then I configure a security group say 'my_sg', each rule of which has a single port open (say 22), and its source being security group 'my_ips'.  Then I allocate 'my_sg' to my EC2 instance.

What I'm trying to avoid is having to configure multiple rules in 'my_sg' for each port, each rule having the same port but different IP.  I'm trying to have 'my_ips' rules filter by IP, then 'my_sg' rules filter by port number.

No luck.  Clearly I am doing it wrong.  Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're mistaken about how security groups work. When you choose to allow an SG as the source in a rule for another SG, you're saying that any EC2 instance that is a member of that SG is permitted on the port you specify. It is not related to the rules of the source SG.

I understand that you're trying to specify all the addresses that should be allowed for port 22 within a single rule, but unfortunately that's no possible with security groups currently. You need to express each IP address and port as its own rule.

Comment: Hi Ben, Still it needs to express each IP address for a single port? I want to express around 10 IPs (which are completely different from each other) for port 80.

Comment: @Ben I want to add 1 one thing you can add list of IPs in it. Setting CIDR/IP so anyone can in that list can access it. Like, if we have

103.120.20.195/28 as CIDR in security group. Following IPs can access it.

103.120.20.192
103.120.20.193
103.120.20.194
103.120.20.195
103.120.20.196
103.120.20.197
103.120.20.198
103.120.20.199
103.120.20.200
103.120.20.201
103.120.20.202
103.120.20.203
103.120.20.204
103.120.20.205
103.120.20.206
103.120.20.207

Note: The reason behind that sometimes our ips have changes dynamically, and our IP provider use some specific ranges.

Comment: For people reading this in the future because it keeps coming up on search hits:  the way to do this (at least in the early 2020's) is to put all the IP addresses in a [*managed prefix list*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/managed-prefix-lists.html).  Then in the SG rule, use the prefix list ID ("pl-12345...") as the source/destination address.  That protocol/port/etc assignment then takes effect for the entire centrally-managed list of addresses.  1/2

Comment: Be aware, however, that (1) the _managed prefix list_ is managed in the VPC settings; OP's question was about EC2-Classic and I've no idea if it's available there.  More importantly, (2) each individual combination of "IP address" and "protocol/port" counts as using up a rule.  A given SG can only have (as of current writing) 50 or so total rules.  So be judicious in your prefix list CIDR blocks and which ports you want to allow.  (You can use more than one SG per EC2 instance, though.)  2/2